# I have purchased a Nema 1.8 Degree step angle stepper motor. How can i rotate it at 1.2 degrees?

Tags: arduino, iot

I want to rotate my motor at 1.2 degrees.
Do I need to purchase any other components for this?

Comment: Did you purchased some driver? Or just the Nema 1.8 Stepper motor?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about *software* development.

Comment: In addition to microstepping options, you can also consider things like toothed timing or power transmission belts (which can sometimes simplify the mechanical situation and provide useful vibration isolation and absorb small misalignment in addition to providing a ratio) or even in today's world custom 3d-printed double-herringbone gears off a cheap everyday filament printer.

Answer (score 0):

There are off the shelf microstepping drivers which allow control of a stepper motor less than one step, but I don't know of any which allow a fraction of a third - usually they divide a step by powers of two.

The arduino stepping library supports microstep divisions of 2, 4, and 8 so you could look at what is done in the code [there](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Stepper/pull/5/files#) and change that for a ⅓ division. Then you take two ⅓ steps for 1.2 degrees.

Comment: With a finer step microstepping driver, even if an exact ratio is not possible it may be possible track the *desired* position in software with a yet higher precision but move the motor to a cruder approximation, at least avoiding *cumulative* error.